# how to bring same category columns under a single header in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, data-analysis

I am new to pandas and facing difficulty to get an idea, to solve this problem, can someone help me with a way to approach this.

I have a source dataframe in the below format
[image]

Here I am sharing the code to generate source dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Employee ID":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Name":["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
               "Departments":["hr", "hr, manager", "manager", "developer", "tester, manager, developer"],
               "Groups":["group-1", "group-2, group-3", "", "", "group-1"]})
```

print(df)

[image]

I would like to convert it to the below format
[image: expected output]

I have tried with pivot table and other [stackover flow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791839/is-there-an-easy-way-to-group-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe) but it's not helping much, can someone help me a way to understand and solve this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe [reprex] with simple input data as text and exected output? Images are not so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom function with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), then if need replace values by columns names add [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but first convert columns for not processing to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
def f(x):
    m = x.str.get_dummies(', ').astype(bool)
    a = np.where(m, m.columns, '')
    return pd.DataFrame(a, columns=m.columns, index=x.index)

df1 = df.set_index(['Employee ID','Name'])

df = pd.concat([f(df1[x]) for x in df1.columns], axis=1, keys=df1.columns)
print (df)
                 Departments                        Groups                  
                   developer  hr  manager  tester  group-1  group-2  group-3
Employee ID Name                                                            
1           A                 hr                   group-1                  
2           B                 hr  manager                   group-2  group-3
3           C                     manager                                   
4           D      developer                                                
5           E      developer      manager  tester  group-1
```

Comment: Hi, @jezrael thank you very much, for the clear explanation :) it worked as expected!!